# Emberjs redirect in a view

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I am building a log-in form in Ember.

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend(
 // states here);

Then I have the following view

```
App.SignInView = Ember.View.extend
templateName: 'signin'

submitLogin: (event) ->
    login = @getPath('email.value')
    password = @getPath('password.value')
    console.log "Login: " + login + " Password: " + password
    // how do I redirect to a different state? I.e. "loggedIn"
```

submitLogin is triggered from the template by using {{action "submitLogin"}}

As you see from this snippet, I want to check a username/password before showing the "private" area of the web app. What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 3):

You should implement your `submitLogin` hander inside the current route, and transition route from the handler, which becomes something like:

```coffeescript
submitLogin: (router, event) ->
  login = event.context.email // e.g
  password = event.context.password // e.g

  // do ajax call here...
    // and from reply handlers:
    router.transitionTo('loggedIn');
```

You will have to pass the email & password container in the action helper, e.g: `{{action submitLogin this}}`

Comment: So basically it means that all events, after which I change the  state of the application should be passed to the routes. Originally I was expecting this to be handled by controllers.

Comment: Actually, my understanding was that event handling was to be contained within views (rather than controllers) for the most part, and it was even my impression that the purpose of extending Ember.View is to handle events. Can anyone recommend any "best practice"-type rules for this?

Comment: @AndreiVaranovich Controllers are intended to be proxy on data, and to contains value added primitives, but router state should always be modified from within itself.

Comment: @pauldechov Views should, as their name indicates, only contain rendering stuff, like computed properties, style... and so on.

Comment: Anyhow, I think it might be a nice feature to support calling router from View/Controller. Obviously both View and Controller can "partially" handle some logic, e.g. react on some user events. Well, ok, at least Views can do that. Perhaps somebody from Emberjs team has an opinion on this. Otherwise I will try to report this feature request on Github.

Comment: BTW, @MikeAski I try this {{view Ember.TextField viewName="email"}}  and I get event.context.email in the event handler as "undefined".

Comment: I realized that I missed to define the "fields" for binding in my view. So far everything works. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeAski BTW, I realized that since the event handling logic has been moved into the router, it is now not obvious how to perform a basic validation of the form (e.g. email conforms a certain RegEx). Seems this is the case when handling event first in the view class and only then in the router would work better.

Answer (score 1):

This discussion [Ember.js get view triggering event in the router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865099/ember-js-get-view-triggering-event-in-the-router/11872383) led me to the following design:

1. Let the view handling the event
2. Forward the event to the router by using smth. like this inside the view

   ```
   App.router.send('signUp',context)
   ```

The key thing here is that I don't need to change the state of the router outside the router, but rather send the context to be handled by the *current* state of the router.

Comment: Instead of referring to an absolute path, you can use `this.get('controller.target')` where `this` is the view.