# Ember.js get view triggering event in the router

Tags: ember.js

I have a view triggers an event which is handled inside the router state.

```
<button {{action signUp this}} type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign-Up</button>
```

here is a handler:

```
signUp: (router, event) ->
    //how do I get an instance of the "View" class triggered an event?
```

I can use event.context to get all bound properties of the View class, but in fact I want to get a complete instance of the View class which has triggered the event. Any hints how to achieve this?

Comment: replacing this by the view keyword should work. But I wonder why you need to have the view instance in the handler

Comment: I vant to put some validation logic inside the view. E.g. I want to check if the passwords match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do validations etc. in the view, I'd recommend to call the action on the view

```
// template
{{action signUp target="parentView"}}
```

and there send the event to the router via

```
// view
signUp: function() {
    // validation etc
    App.router.send('signUp',context);
}
```

You could manipulate your context to contain a reference to the current view (`this`) as well if you need to.

Hope that helped!